# How to parse json with retrofit in android

Tags: android, json, retrofit

please I need your help, I want to parse the following json in my app with retrofit in android, but the problem is that I don't know how to create my model classes,
I want to show title, rankings, name, titre, difference and points of each ranking,

My json:

```
    {
"channel": {},
"classification": [
            {
            "day": {
                "id": "3169",
                "accr": "J8",
                "type": "0",
                "title": "8ème journée",
                "start": "2016-10-08",
                "finish": "2016-10-09",
                "poolid": "36",
                "pool_name": null,
                "rankings": {
                        "1": {
                            "club": {},
                            "evolution": {},
                            "difference": "77"

                            },
                        "2": {
                            "club": {},
                            "evolution": {},
                            "difference": "47"

                            },
                        "3": {
                            "club": {},
                            "evolution": {},
                            "difference": "61"

                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
}
```

my top14

```
{
"channel": {},
"classification": [
            {
            "day": {
                "id": "3169",
                "accr": "J8",
                "type": "0",
                "title": "8ème journée",
                "start": "2016-10-08",
                "finish": "2016-10-09",
                "poolid": "36",
                "pool_name": null,
                "rankings": {
                        "1": {
                            "club": {},
                            "evolution": {},
                            "difference": "77"

                            },
                        "2": {
                            "club": {},
                            "evolution": {},
                            "difference": "47"

                            },
                        "3": {
                            "club": {},
                            "evolution": {},
                            "difference": "61"

                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
}
```

my top14lst

```
public class Top14List {
    @SerializedName("classification")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<Top> classification = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<Top> getClassification() {
        return classification;
    }
    public void setClassification(ArrayList<Top> classification) {
        this.classification = classification;
    }
}
```

my top

```
public class Top {

    private Map<String, Day> day;

    public Map<String, Day> getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(Map<String, Day> day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
}
```

my Day

```
public class Day {

    private String title;
    private String start;
    private String finish;

    private Map<String, Rankings> rankings;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(String start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String getFinish() {
        return finish;
    }

    public void setFinish(String finish) {
        this.finish = finish;
    }

    public Map<String, Rankings> getRankings() {
        return rankings;
    }

    public void setRankings(Map<String, Rankings> rankings) {
        this.rankings = rankings;
    }
}
```

my group

```
public class Group1 {

    private Map<String, Club> club;
    private String difference;


    public Map<String, Club> getClub() {
        return club;
    }

    public void setClub(Map<String, Club> club) {
        this.club = club;
    }

    public String getDifference() {
        return difference;
    }

    public void setDifference(String difference) {
        this.difference = difference;
    }


}
```

but the problem i don't know how to code the ranking class "1" "2" "3"

can you please help me

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me. Why do you need to code "1","2" and so on? You have got Map<String,Ranking> and you have got Group. Just replace group with Rankings and then you can access values with iterator. Also as @MohanadMohie mentioned your json is incorrect, rankings is an array not an object. It should have square braces

Answer (score 0):

Try [this website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), where you can enter your JSON string and it generates the Java Class for you.

Edit:

Try this modified JSON with the website and it should generate your Java models:

```
{
   "channel":{
      "title":"jeux"
   },
   "classification":{
      "day":{
         "id":"3175",
         "accr":"J5",
         "type":"0",
         "title":"xxxxxxxx",
         "start":"2016-09-17",
         "finish":"2016-09-18",
         "poolid":"36",
         "pool_name":null,
         "rankings":{
            "1":{
               "cal":{
                  "id":"12",
                  "name":"yyyyy",
                  "logo":{
                     "titre":"sssssssssssssssssssss.png",
                     "date":"2014-12-08 15:23:49",
                     "fichier":"image/png",
                     "url":"http://www.qWSi",
                     "taille":23528,
                     "largeur":116,
                     "hauteur":150
                  }
               },
               "difference":"65",
               "points":"18"
            },
            "2":{
               "cal":{
                  "id":"41",
                  "name":"aaaaaa",
                  "logo":{
                     "titre":"fsdfdsfsddf.png",
                     "date":"2016-07-06 15:35:01",
                     "fichier":"image/png",
                     "url":"http://www.M8ZBH1Be",
                     "taille":23475,
                     "largeur":122,
                     "hauteur":150
                  }
               },
               "difference":"65",
               "points":"18"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thnks for your suggestion but that does not help, I have problem in loops in my json, I don't know how to declare "1", "2", ...until "13" in my POJO classes inside the POJO  class "Rankings"

can you please help me, it's really important, thanks

Comment: This JSON is not correct to start with. 1-"rankings" should be an array, and 2- Each item has an extra comma at its end. The way it is now, Rankings is not an array, but an object that has 13 objects inside it, each named as a number. I also think "classification" should be an object, not an array, judging from this snippet. I could be wrong though. I updated my answer with how I think the JSON should be. You might want to modify it a little depending on your data because I don't have full understanding of your data, but this will put you on the right track, I hope.

Comment: Hello
I don't have any control on json

Comment: I have do a modification in the question

Comment: The JSON still has a problem, if you have absolutely no control over the JSON you might want to manually parse this part from the response's JSON String. See, "rankings" is a JSON Object that has sub-objects "1", "2", "3". To properly create a corresponding java class, the "1" object variable in the class must be: `private Ranking 1;`, which is not allowed in java as variable names can't start with a digit. [Refer to this link for variable naming in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).